# How to insert new data in pandas dataframe by referencing to a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I've got a pandas dataframe `df` as follow:

```
Supervisor  Student   Age
  Dr.A        ken     19
  Dr.A        jay     19
  Dr.B        tom     20
  Dr.C        kay     21
```

and now I wanna add a new column `'Status'` to this dataframe to become:

```
Supervisor  Student   Age   Status
  Dr.A        ken     19      
  Dr.A        jay     19      
  Dr.B        tom     20      
  Dr.C        kay     21
```

the data in `'Status'` is referenced to a list `profile`:

```
['Dr.A', 'jay -ken +', 'Dr.B', 'tom R3', 'Dr.C', 'kay']
```

how to achieve the expected output as below?

```
Supervisor  Student   Age   Status
  Dr.A        ken     19      +
  Dr.A        jay     19      -
  Dr.B        tom     20      R3
  Dr.C        kay     21
```

Comment: Is no separator between `jay -ken +` ? Is imposible instead `list` create `dict` like `d = {'DR.A':'jay-|ken +', 'Dr.B': 'tom R3', ...}` ? Is separator whitesapce always between `jay -` and similar for all values?

Comment: Unfortunately, no separator exists.